# Dynamic accesskey on DIV in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to provide dynamic accesskey to DIV inside the common component, which may be used at many places. Here is the code for the same:

```
<div id="{{id}}-xyz" class="xyz" accesskey="accessKey">

...

</div>
```

Where, `accesskey` is a typescript variable.

The issue with above code is, the accesskey always got the value "accessKey" and not treating it as the variable and get the actual value stored inside the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variable from component you shuuld use [] around of attribute. Also for attributes you should use `attr.` prefix ([more details](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property)) for your case is should look like:

```
<div id="{{id}}-xyz" class="xyz" [attr.accesskey]="accessKey">

...

</div>
```